# rails server not starting - trying to run code from ryan bates railscasts application with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I am trying to work with ryan bates' sample code that he uses for his railscast on Daemon (episode 129).  I have rails 3 installed, and when I downloaded his code, I cannot run the server.  To try and fix this, I copied my gemfile and gemfile.lock from a standard rails 3 application, and put it into his application, then ran bundle install.  Still, my rails server does not respond.  Instead, I get the following (see below).

My guess is that I am having issues because railscasts uses rails 2 (I believe) whereas I am using rails 3.  Is there any way that I can still use his program?

Thanks.

Usage:

```
rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

Options:

```
-r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /home/kyala/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
-d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)enter code here
                              # Default: sqlite3
 -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails 
checkout
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails 
repository
[--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
 -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
 -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
 -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
 -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps

Runtime options:
-f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
-p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
 -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
 -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
 -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
```

Description:
     The `rails new` command creates a new Rails application with a default
     directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:

```
rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
```

This generates a skeletal Rails installation in `~/Code/Ruby/weblog`.

See the README in the newly created application to get going.

Comment: what command are you running?

Comment: you need to use "ruby script/server".. "rails server" applies to rails >= 3.0

Comment: As per the guide, the version used was 2.1.0. Better install 2.1.0 or try to convert the older app with rails higher verisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not going to work this way. there are too many differences between rails 3.x and 2.x (different behavior of rails command, different config, bundler etc).

i would create a new rails project and just copy the app folder from the screencast.

anyways, this is not a good idea, as the gems that are used for rails 2.x are different from those in rails 3.x so you will most likely experience some errors with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

To run server in rails 3 you should use following command from your source folder:

```
rails server
```

But I think it's easier to install rails 2 and appropriate version of ruby than trying to fight issues of migrating from rails 2 to rails 3. To switch between different ruby version you may use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/).